# Omitting the word "to"

Tags: prepositions, omissibility

Will omitting "to" change the meaning of these sentences?

1. Luffy, name one mall you've been *to*.
2. In the places you've been *to*, did you see any dragon balls?

Comment: It wouldn't change the meaning of the sentences, but the version without _to_ is simply not considered grammatical by all speakers. There are speakers who _so_ use sentences like "I liked every mall I've been". I don't think it's wisely considered standard English, though.

Answer (score 1):

It *would* change the meaning of your first example. When you end a sentence with the verb been, you are asking if they themselves have existed as a mall. What is one mall you've existed as? It doesn't make any sense.

However, in the second sentence, it's more of a slang usage. You have actually BEEN in those places, so it's describing that.

Answer (score 0):

> Luffy, name one mall you have been to.

You go *to* a place.: *Name one city you have been to.  Name one village you have been to.*
Without "to" the sentence would be incorrect.

> In the places you've been to, did you see any dragon balls?

You could say *"Did you see any Dragon balls in the places you have been?"*  without any change in meaning.
It is clear you are referring to a place; therefore you can omit "to".